# Cannot resolve symbol 'HasRequired' Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to connect two tables by means of code in C# with Entity Framework Core.

The classes are:

```
public class roll
{
    [key]
    public int rollId { get; set; }

    public List<pieces> pieces { get; set; }
}

public class pieces
{
    [Key]
    public int pieceId { get; set; }
    public int quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal price { get; set; }
}
```

In my `DbContext`, I have the following method:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<roll>()
                .HasRequired(m => m.quantity)
                .WithMany(m => m.pieces)
                .HasForeignKey(m => m.pieceId);

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

`HasRequired` turns red and gives this message:

> EntityTypeBuilder does not contain a definition for HasRequired.

The project has added a reference to `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational`.
I have recompiled the solution, closed and opened visual studio and I cannot solve that `HasRequired` stops being red

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: First you should have a `public roll roll{get;set;}`and `public int rollId {get;set;}` in `pieces` and then it should be `modelBuilder.Entity<pieces>().HasRequired(p => p.roll).WithMany(r => r.pieces).HasForeignKey(p => p.rollId);`  That would be the proper way to setup a one to many relationship from roll to pieces.

Answer (score 9):

You should change your code for .net core EF, they just removed `HasRequired` and replace it with `HasOne` for one-to-one relationship and `HasMany` for one-to-many relations. You Can Also add `.IsRequired()` for required relations. Good Luck.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<roll>()
            .HasOne(m => m.quantity).IsRequired()
            .WithMany(m => m.pieces)
            .HasForeignKey(m => m.pieceId);
```

You can find complete documentation here : [Documentation link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key)

Answer (score 2):

Entity Framework Core does not have `HasRequired()` - that's an old Entity Framework <=6 (.NET Framework) method.

EF Core instead uses `HasOne()`. You can see more on their official documentation [here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#required-and-optional-relationships)